# В чем причина появления легкого выделения по углам картинки и как от него избавиться

Tags: html, css

По краям картинки проступают темные пиксели от background-color. (либо сразу, либо при ресайзе страницы в зависимости от браузера)
Почему так происходит? Как от них избавиться, если обязательно иметь и   background-color, и background-image одновременно + background-repeat: no-repeat;

Если убрать 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
то обводка по краям исчезает. Возможно есть способ по-другому имитировать это свойство?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XovwMK

```css
.a {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("https://cs.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013-01_2/1357482852_1814017829.jpg");
  border-radius: 24px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: background-size: cover;

Comment: не помогает 
проблема остается